Picture-in-Picture video time jumps during rotation, when recording with mobile phone
I use my phone for streaming live videos to my server the usual way with javascript and getUserMedia() etc.
Then I'm using FFMPEG to encode it in realtime and additionally put an overlay video onto it.
For some reason, each time I rotate the phone to landscape mode or back to portrait mode, the overlay video will jump forward in time. The overlay video is not being modified while the live stream is encoding. It's just a video file from the hard-drive, no stream. Any ideas whats going on?
I tried different FFMPEG versions, but the behaviour is always the same.
Orange is the livestream. Green is the overlay:

Video Sample
Here is a short sample of whats going on.
Works after downloading 2mb
Sample
Works with the online Mega Player 23mb
Sample
FFMPEG Command
ffmpeg -re -i strm.webm -i overlay.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decreasepad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[main];[1]scale=iw/1.5:-1setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=yuva420p[ovrl]; [main][ovrl]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]; [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -r 24 -deadline realtime -crf 22 -cpu-used 15 -level 2.0 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a aac -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt nv12 -threads 4 -strict -2 -auto-alt-ref 0 -b:v:1 1800k -s:v:1 1280x720 -b:v:0 300k -s:v:0 640x480 -bf 1 -keyint_min 48 -g 48 -sc_threshold 1 -b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 96000 -scenario livestreaming -look_ahead 0 -seg_duration 2 -remove_at_exit 1 -streaming 1 -window_size 30 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -utc_timing_url https://time.akamai.com/?iso -live 1 -y -f dash manifest.mpd


It could be related to gaps in the timestamps of the input video during rotation. Try "forcing" the timestamps to say 30fps using setpts filter: [0:v]setpts=N/TB/30,scale=640:480.... Try it without the audio (add -an before -i). You may look for timestamps issue using FFprobe: ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time strm.webm. Note that in theory rotation shouldn't affect the timestamps (it's only a guess). Consider sharing a sample video (using Google Drive for example).

Add -reinit_filter 0 before -i strm.webm and check.

@Gyan This will crash the encoding graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 000001f68ba216c0] Changing video frame properties on the fly is not supported by all filters. [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 000001f68ba216c0] filter context - w: 480 h: 640 fmt: 0 csp: smpte170m range: tv, incoming frame - w: 640 h: 480 fmt: 0 csp: smpte170m range: tv pts_time: 24.795

@Rotem It's hard to tell if this helps because it makes the encoding very unstable. The stream will freeze for many seconds on rotation or even end prematurely. But when it starts again it seems like the time jump is very small(I counted the seconds while it's freezing).

@Macster not if the scale is the first filter that this input is passed to, like in this command.

@Gyan This is crashing on rotation: ffmpeg -re -reinit_filter 0 -i "strm.webm" -i "overlay.webm" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decreasepad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[main];[1]scale=iw/1.5:-1setpts=PTS-STARTPTSformat=yuva420p[ovrl]; [main][ovrl]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]; [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -r 24 ...

As @Rotem rightly pointed out, “setpts” was the problem.
For some reason, resolution change, caused by the rotation, led to new incorrect timestamps being set by “setpts” for the overlay. So I just removed the setpts option.
No setpts, no new false timestamps.
So the filter_complex simply looks like this:
-filter_complex [0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[main];[1]scale=iw/1.5:-1,format=yuva420p[ovrl]; [main][ovrl]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]; [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]"

